# Pass jQuery object array to PHP with JSON

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

How can I access the "code" and "type" values in PHP once I passed the array?
BTW, I'm using the "jquery-json" plugin. Is there any way to do this without any plugins?

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    function product(code, type) {

        return {
            code: code,
            type: type
        }

    }

    var products = [];

    products.push(product("333", "Product one"), product("444", "Second product"));

    var jsonProducts = $.toJSON(products); 

    $.post(
        "php/process.php",
        {products: jsonProducts},
        function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    );


});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

$products = json_decode($_POST["products"], true);

foreach ($products as $product){
    echo $product;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your array offsets is a basic object.

```
foreach ($products as $product)
{
    echo $product->code;
    echo $product->type;
}
```

I'd suggest that you re-read the examples on [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to get a better understanding on how PHP translates JSON to PHP types

Comment: Yeah, this is what I first tried but I get this: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in..."

Comment: When I do print_r I get the correct array strcuture: Array ( [code] => 333 [type] => Product one ) Array ( [code] => 444 [type] => Second product )

Comment: Yeah! That works! But why the associative array doesn't work?

Comment: Oh, I got it! I have don't use "true" in json_decode for it to work. Thanks

Comment: @elclanrs, adding true as the second argument decodes the JSON to an associative array rather than an object. As you 've found :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do `$product->code` and `$product->type` in your foreach loop.

By the way, if you want to print an array structure to check the formatting, you can use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).